# How to paste a pattern based on a FILENAME using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

Template `A.tsv`:

```
Name    data
B
C
```

And several files to analyse, for example, `B.txt`:

```
#bla
#blabla
16  LSD
```

and `C.txt`:

```
#bla
#blabla
16  ARH
```

I want to add OK or KO to `A.tsv` based on whether `LSD` is present in the other files:

```
Name    data
B   OK
C   KO
```

The field separators are tabs (`\t`) for all files. How to do that with awk?

I started with FILENAME recognition but no clue for the rest:

```
template="A.tsv"
for bla in data/*.txt ; do
r="$(basename -s ".txt" $bla)"
( head -n 1 $template
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" -v filename=$r  [..........] >> output_final.tsv;
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
  !last && /LSD/{seen[FILENAME]=1; nextfile;}
  last{
    if (FNR<2) print
    else print $1 "\t" ( seen[$1".txt"] ? "OK" : "KO" )
  }
' *.txt last=1 A.tsv
```

First Awk reads the `txt` files, for which `last` is unset, and looks for a `LSD` match. If found, it puts the filename in the `seen` array (`nextfile` is just an optimization). When it reaches the `A.tsv` file `last` is set, so it prints its header and checks for each remaining line if the corresponding filename is in `seen`, adding `<tab>OK` if yes and `<tab>KO` if not.